# Setting up the Java variables in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to install Amazon Mturk command line tool on Ubuntu 13.10 ( 32-bit) system.

After setting the access secrete and access identifier in mturk.properties file, I ran the getBalance.sh file and below is the output.

```
./getBalance.sh
You must set JAVA_HOME (i.e. export JAVA_HOME=/usr)
If you do not have JAVA on your machine, you can download it from http://java.sun.com/
./../bin/invoke.sh: 41: exit: Illegal number: -1
```

The following is the java information on my system

```
$ file `which java javac`
/usr/bin/java:  symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'
/usr/bin/javac: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/javac'
```

My shell information is :

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

**But, $JAVA_HOME command gave me a blank line as result.**

I can see the java installed on my machine :

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java
```

I thought everything is correct now, but here is what I get if I run the getBalnace.sh

```
$ ./getBalance.sh 
./../bin/invoke.sh: 79: exec: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: not found
```

I checked my environment variables, below is the result

```
$ env | grep java
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
```

And the path is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/sid/.rvm/bin
```

I still could not figure out where am I doing wrong. The sentences below are quite confusing and no much information is available.

- If you downloaded the Unix distribution, you must set the
  MTURK_CMD_HOME environment variable to point to your Command Line
  Tools installation location.
- If you downloaded the Unix distribution, you must set the JAVA_HOME
  environment variable to point to your Java Standard Edition Runtime
  Environment (JRE) installation location.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the Java world, JAVA_HOME refers to the directory where the JDK or JRE was installed. So you should be able to find the java executable at

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

In your case, find the physical location where java is installed. Something like this should work:

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/javac
```

A typical response would be

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

For this response, you should set JAVA_HOME to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```